# Dynamic data in Laravel/Blade for subset of views

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I have a model for a productgroup that links to the products via an ID. When the user clicks on a productgroup, I want to show a menu on the left side where the user can click on a link to edit

1. the productgroup and
2. the products in the productgroup.

There are also other pages in the same menu. For example a page about "managing the homepage", resulting in the fact that not every page (view) is able to deliver a productgroup or list of single products.

I have this menu structure:

- Edit homepage
- Productgroup

  - Edit brand information
  - Edit seo text
  - Edit warranty info
- Product 1

  - Edit Basic info product 1
  - Edit Facts product 1
- Product 2

  - Edit Basic info product 1
  - Edit Facts product 1

What I want to achieve is that for some views I pass the corresponding **"products"** to the view. That way I can create a list in the menu. However, some controllers don't have that info (e.g. the edit homepage controller), so I can't pass it to the view. When the controller does not pass the info to the view, the view gives an error.

I have a very basic setup of views:

- *app.blade.php* includes some general views
- *app.blade.php* yields the specific views that are loaded by the controller

In *app.blade.php* I pass, for example, some values to the menu:

```
@include('backoffice/menu', array('ProductGroup'=>$vars['groupinfo'], 'Products'=>$vars['productinfo']))
```

What is the best way to build up the dynamic menu?

Comment: Have you tried creating a view composer for that view which supplies the required data?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Comment: The problem as far as i can see with a view composer is that it's loaded in every view. But I only know the productgroup ID if the user is on a page where a productgroup or product is selected. So not in every view.

Comment: You set the composer on the `backoffice/menu` view so it's only loaded when that view is included somewhere.  Then you'd see if `$request->has('productGroupId')` and if it does, grab your data and pass it to the view.

Comment: Ok, so i think i did not explain it very well. The URL can be e.g.localhost/public/backoffice/productgroup/1/edit or localhost/public/backoffice/product/1/edit. As you can see the "1" in the URL can either refer to the specific productgroup or to a specific product. I think I need to find a way for sending the “pagetype” to the composer. Correct? If so, any idea to fix that?

Comment: How are you determining the difference right now?  In your routes, are both of those defined using the same placeholder, for example {productId}?

Comment: I can acces the view variables in the composer. In my controllers i can add some var and create the menu based on those vars. Within the viewcomposer i can build the menu logic on a central location. But it would be better if I can use the id’s in the url. Maybe via the route settings. But at the moment all those id’s have different var’s. When I can make it work with 1 var (e.g. productgroupvar, productvar) and I can access it it’s more centralized. My routes file has rows like e.g. 
Route::resource('bo/ProductGroupBasic', 'bo\ProductGroupBasic'); Any idea what direction I should look?